# Resize parent LinearLayout when adding Buttons Programatically

Tags: android, resize, android-linearlayout

so what i want to do is add buttons to a LinearLayout programaticalls, this works fine. I want them to apper as one line of buttons in a horizontal order so i set the LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/button_frame"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

Then i add the buttons programatically:

```
for (String text: textlist) {

        Button cbut = new Button(context);
        cbut.setText(text);
        cbut.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        cbut.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.d(LOGTAGNAME, "TEST: " + buttonText);
            }
        });

        button_frame.addView(cbut);
        button_frame.invalidate();
    }
```

This works until the buttons extend the screen width. So what i want to happen is that there is a horizontal scollbar if the buttons extend the screen width. As an alternative there could be a "line break" for the buttons inside the LinearLayout.

I've tried different setups including a scrollview around the listview but i never saw a scrollbar.

So maybe my problem is that the LinearLayout is not resizing correctly? What do i have to do to make the LinearLayout recalculate width every time after a view is added? invalidate() has no effect at all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the linearlayout inside a horiztonalscrollview. That should provide the scrollbar once the button exceeds the screen width.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot. That was all i needed to do. Using a horizontalscrollview instead of just the scrollview. now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You trying a simple scrollview or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html ? If you don't trying HorizontalScrollView, I think that must help.

Answer (score 1):

try `HorizontalScrollView`  and add Buttons to it . this will scroll automatically whenever needed . for more help share complete layout code

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` provide only "linear" positioning of views ;) I mean you can do like this:

```
[btn1][btn2][btn3][btn4]
```

or like this:

```
[btn1]
[btn2]
[btn3]
[btn4]
```

Difference between two variants is in `android:orientation` param. For more complicated views you should use `TableLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

If you want to do  scrollable variant of linear layout creta this structure:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     ...any other params...>
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="horisontal"
         ...any other params.../>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

and add buttons to linear layout like you do it now.